# When i run at screen is white/blank

Tags: android, eclipse

Ok when i run the VideoRecorder activity my app is blank, cant seem to find the problem in my code. No errors in the VideoRecorder activity but it still just shows a white blank screen when i run it on my phone.

What the logcat says

```
04-27 12:50:22.533: W/System.err(31693):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
04-27 12:50:22.533: W/System.err(31693):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
04-27 12:50:22.533: W/System.err(31693):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
04-27 12:50:22.533: W/System.err(31693):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
04-27 12:50:22.533: W/System.err(31693):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
04-27 12:50:22.533: W/System.err(31693):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 12:50:24.906: W/System.err(31693):    ... 20 more
04-27 12:50:24.906: W/System.err(31693):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-27 12:50:24.906: W/System.err(31693):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-27 12:50:24.906: W/System.err(31693):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 12:50:24.906: W/System.err(31693):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-27 12:50:24.906: W/System.err(31693):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-27 12:50:24.906: W/System.err(31693):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
```

Here is code for the activity

```
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class VideoRecorder extends Activity {

private String audiofile;
private Button backbtn;
private Button btn_save;
private Button btnSound;
private ToggleButton cameraSwitch;
private int cameraType = 0;



private View.OnClickListener click = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView) {
        switch (paramAnonymousView.getId())
        {
        case R.layout.powered_by:
        case R.id.layout:
        default:
            return;
        case R.id.btn_save:
            VideoRecorder.this.chooseSaveDialog();
            return;
        case R.id.backbtn:
            VideoRecorder.this.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

    }
};
Context contex;
int count = 0;
String fileName;
String filePath;
boolean flag = false;
boolean frontCam;
SurfaceHolder holder;
LayoutInflater inflater;
boolean isPlaySound = false;
boolean isRecording = true;
private Preview mPreview;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private Camera myCamera;
PackageManager pm;
boolean rearCam;
private MediaRecorder recorder;
RelativeLayout rootLayout;
boolean startedRecording = false;
boolean stoppedRecording = false;
long timestamp;

private Camera getCameraInstance(int paramInt)
{
    try
    {
        Camera localCamera = Camera.open(paramInt);
        return localCamera;
    }
    catch (Exception localException) {}
    return null;
}

private void initCameraView(MediaRecorder paramMediaRecorder)
{
    try 
    {
        if (this.mPreview != null) {
            this.rootLayout.removeView(this.mPreview);
        }
        this.mPreview = ((Preview)this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_layout, null));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1);
        this.mPreview.setvActivity(this);
        this.mPreview.setTempRecorder(paramMediaRecorder);
        this.mPreview.setFilePath(this.filePath);
        this.holder = this.mPreview.getHolder();
        this.rootLayout.addView(this.mPreview, localLayoutParams);
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            localException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void initData()
{
    this.audiofile = getIntent().getStringExtra(audiofile);
    if (this.audiofile == null) {}
}

private void initView()
{
    this.btn_save = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save));
    this.backbtn = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.backbtn));
    this.btnSound = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSound));
    this.cameraSwitch = ((ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.cameraSwitch));
    this.rootLayout = ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout));
    if (!this.frontCam) {
        this.cameraSwitch.setVisibility(8);
    }
}

private void mediaRecorderSetup()
{
    this.myCamera = getCameraInstance(this.cameraType);
    this.recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    this.myCamera.unlock();
    this.recorder.setCamera(this.myCamera);
    this.recorder.setAudioSource(1);
    this.recorder.setVideoSource(1);
    this.recorder.setOutputFormat(0);
    this.recorder.setAudioEncoder(0);
    this.recorder.setVideoEncoder(0);
    this.recorder.setOutputFile(this.filePath);
    initCameraView(this.recorder);
}

private void releaseCamera()
{
    if (this.myCamera != null)
    {
      this.myCamera.release();
      this.myCamera = null;
    }
  }

  private void releaseMediaRecorder()
  {
    if (this.recorder != null)
    {
      this.recorder.reset();
      this.recorder.release();
      this.recorder = null;
      this.myCamera.lock();
    }
  }

private void setListener()
{
    this.btn_save.setOnClickListener(this.click);
    this.backbtn.setOnClickListener(this.click);
    this.btnSound.setOnClickListener(this.click);
    this.cameraSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton paramAnonymousCompoundButton, boolean paramAnonymousBoolean) {
            VideoRecorder localVideoRecorder = VideoRecorder.this;
            localVideoRecorder.count = (1 + localVideoRecorder.count);
            if (VideoRecorder.this.count % 2 == 0) {}
            for (VideoRecorder.this.cameraType = 0;;)
            {
                VideoRecorder.this.releaseMediaRecorder();
                VideoRecorder.this.releaseCamera();
                VideoRecorder.this.timestamp = new Date().getTime();
                VideoRecorder.this.filePath = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + String.valueOf(VideoRecorder.this.timestamp) + ".3gpp");
                VideoRecorder.this.mediaRecorderSetup();
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void startRecording()
{
    if (this.recorder != null) {
        this.recorder.start();
    }
}

private void stopRecording()
{
    if (this.recorder != null)
    {
        this.recorder.stop();
        this.recorder.release();
        this.recorder = null;
    }
}

public void chooseSaveDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    localBuilder.setTitle("Save.");
    localBuilder.setMessage("Press OK to save");
    localBuilder.setNegativeButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface, int paramAnonymousInt) {
            paramAnonymousDialogInterface.dismiss();
            VideoRecorder.this.releaseMediaRecorder();
            VideoRecorder.this.releaseCamera();
            VideoRecorder.this.stopRecording();
            VideoRecorder.this.StopAudio();
            Intent localIntent = new Intent();
            localIntent.putExtra("result", VideoRecorder.this.filePath);
            VideoRecorder.this.setResult(-1, localIntent);
            VideoRecorder.this.finish();
        }
    });
localBuilder.create().show();
}

public void initRecord()
{
    startRecording();
}

public void onBackPressed()
{
    StopAudio();
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    releaseCamera();
    super.onBackPressed();
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
{
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.recordvideo_layout);
            this.pm = getPackageManager();
    this.frontCam = this.pm.hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.camera.front");
    this.rearCam = this.pm.hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.camera");
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    initView();
    initData();
    setListener();
    this.timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    this.filePath = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + String.valueOf(this.timestamp) + ".3gpp");
    mediaRecorderSetup();
}

public void playAudio()
{
    if (this.mp == null) {
        this.mp = new MediaPlayer();
    }
    try
    {
        AssetFileDescriptor localAssetFileDescriptor = getAssets().openFd(this.audiofile);
        this.mp.setDataSource(localAssetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),   localAssetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), localAssetFileDescriptor.getLength());
        localAssetFileDescriptor.close();
        this.mp.prepare();
        this.mp.setLooping(true);
        this.mp.start();
        this.mp.setVolume(10.0F, 10.0F);
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception localException) {}
}

protected void play_pauseAudio()
{
    if (this.isPlaySound) {}
    for (boolean bool = false;;)
    {
        this.isPlaySound = bool;
        if (!this.isPlaySound) {
            break;
        }
        this.btnSound.setText("Pause Sound");
        playAudio();
        return;
    }
    this.btnSound.setText("Play Sound");
    StopAudio(); 
}

public void StopAudio()
{
    if (this.mp != null)
    {
        this.mp.stop();
        this.mp.release();
        this.mp = null;
    }
}

}
```

Also here is the code for the `manifest.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.soloinc.meip"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity 
        android:name="com.soloinc.meip.Webview" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />


    <intent-filter>
        <!--Viewer filter-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>

      <!-- DEFAULT LAUNCHER filter-->
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name"   android:name="com.soloinc.meip.VideoRecorder" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--custom filter-->
    <intent-filter>

    </intent-filter>

</application>
 </manifest>
```

Heres the code for the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/headerlayout" 
     android:background="@drawable/header" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="50.0dip" 
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/backbtn" 
        android:background="@drawable/backbutton" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="14.0dip" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" />

    <TextView 
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/lime_green" 
        android:id="@+id/textView1userlike" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/app_name" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:id="@+id/btn_save" 
        android:background="@drawable/loginbtn" 
        android:layout_width="70.0dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/save" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@id/headerlayout" />

 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="50.0dip" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:id="@+id/btnSound" 
        android:background="@drawable/loginbtn" 
        android:layout_width="110.0dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/sound"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ToggleButton 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:id="@+id/cameraSwitch" 
        android:background="@drawable/rect_nonselected" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textOn="Rear Camera" 
        android:textOff="Front Camera" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setContentView(R.layout.whatever_layout)` within the `onCreate` method, straight after the `requestWindowFeature` line (usually straight after the call to super)

Comment: thanks for your help it fixed that problem but now the app crashes, just updated my OP.

Comment: The OP has that. `onCreate()` is in an usual spot towards the bottom of the Activity. Since the OP is calling `requestWindowFeature(1);` `setContentView()` has to be called after that. I don't know what the value 1 does without looking it up but that's why it's better to use constant values instead of the integer

Comment: @codeMagic he added that in an edit; user3571363 as he's mentioned you just need to move the line you've added after the requestWindowFeature() line. I'll edit my answer to reflect this

Comment: On my phone now so I'm not certain but I believe requestWindowFesture () was in the OP

Comment: It was, but the setContentView wasn't

Comment: so move setContentView after request?

Comment: i did and now the app is just blank like the original problem i had

Comment: What window feature are you requesting? do you really need it?

Comment: deleted the windowfeature and that doesnt change anything

Comment: You might also want to post `recordvideo_layout.xml`

Comment: Are you getting any errors in logcat? (I'm not sure if you can have decimals in dp) also the custom intent filter at application scope in your manifest shouldn't be there

Comment: No theres nothing in logcat

Comment: Well I don't know if CodeMagic can help, but I have no other suggestions than the ones above and also replacing the 8 in setVisibility(8) with the correct constant eg View.GONE

Comment: actually in the logcat it keeps saying system.error and just keeps saying that in yellow wont stop

Comment: How are you running the application? On a device or an emulator? and from an IDE?

Comment: on a device and from Eclipse

Comment: Well restart your device and eclipse both and then rerun it and see if you get a useful error

Comment: That isn't the whole logcat exception, get the whole thing

Comment: how do copy the whole thing theres alot of lines in logcat

Comment: Just the crash part, where it shows the liens in your app right up to the caused by

Comment: it doesnt crash just blank white, all the messages in the logcat are all yellow and all the tag for each of them says system.error

Answer (score 0):

add `@Override` over your oncreate method. like this

```
@Override //======>> This line
protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
{
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    requestWindowFeature(1);
    this.pm = getPackageManager();
    this.frontCam = this.pm.hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.camera.front");
    this.rearCam = this.pm.hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.camera");
    setContentView(R.layout.recordvideo_layout);
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    initView();
    initData();
    setListener();
    this.timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    this.filePath = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + String.valueOf(this.timestamp) + ".3gpp");
    mediaRecorderSetup();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this would help. Leaving out an override annotation would not crash an application, it's used for IDE hints mostly

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are calling the function requestwindowfeature() after calling setcontentview(). requestwindowfeature() must always be called first.